# negative sign with cell is formatted with a text in it

Tags: excel

I am using format cells to add text to cells.
[image]

My problem is when the cell value is negative. The negative location change to be in front of the text.
[image]

How do you move the negative sign in Excel next to the number (blue line in the picture above)?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try conditional custom formatting.

```
[<0]"tt" -0.000 "ksi";"tt" 0.000 "ksi"
```

[image]